# How to Select Specific portion in a list without the Selection starting at the beginning and ending at the End

Tags: css, css-selectors, children

I have css List

```
li : PLEASE RESTORE ALL DEVICES 
li : Used
li : ip6s+
li : ip7
li : ip7+
li : ip8 
li : ip8+
li : ipX
li : ipXr
li : ipXs
li : ipXs+
li : ....
li : ....
li : ....
li : ....
li : ....
li : ....
```

All I need is ip6s+ to ipXs+ in this list.
How do I select a portion of a list ignoring first two,
and what ever comes after ipXs+.

I tried to use nth-child Selector but i couldn't figure out what arguments to put in.

Expected Result Should be

```
li : ip6s+ 
li : ip7
li : ip7+
li : ip8 
li : ip8+
li : ipX
li : ipXr
li : ipXs
li : ipXs+
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to select specific children after a specfic number, you'd use `:nth-child(n + 2)`
This skips the first 2 elements.

[:nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector.